# ag-grid if filters are empty show no data

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using **ag-grid** free edition with AngularJS.

Is it possible to show row data only when any filter has content?
I have read all documentation and obviously gridoptions and I have found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow as per below steps.

1. Using `(filterChanged)="onFilterChanged($event)"` event, you can make sure if the filter has applied on not.

Code:

```
onFilterChanged(params){
  let filters = params.api.filterManager.allFilters;
  this.filterEnabled = false;
  for(var key in filters) {
    if(filters[key].column.filterActive) {
      this.filterEnabled = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

2. Set a flag `filterEnabled` in the event, use it to decide if to show the data or not. `[rowData]="filterEnabled && rowData"`

You can find working plunk example: **[ag-grid - don't show data if filter is enabled](https://plnkr.co/edit/MmxPSnEoEC7jrU8Uv5MG?p=preview)**

*PS: this solutions has an issue: You need to type the filter string twice to enable the filter. But I hope you can get help from this.*